# complicated MySQL query, variable population

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the columns:

AnswerID, OwnerUserID, CreationDate

How do I populate a fourth column titled (AnswersPosted) with the total number of answers that OwnerUserID has posted up until the CreationDate listed for that AnswerID?

Edit:

Below is an example of what the table should look like. (Sorry I can't post images since I just joined...) I'm interested in getting that last column to display all the right numbers. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Use this solution:

```
SELECT a.AnswerID,
       a.OwnerUserID,
       a.CreationDate,
       b.cnt AS AnswersPosted
FROM   tbl a
JOIN   (
       SELECT    a.OwnerUserID,
                 a.CreationDate,
                 COUNT(b.OwnerUserID) AS cnt
       FROM      tbl a
       LEFT JOIN tbl b ON a.OwnerUserID  = b.OwnerUserID
                      AND b.CreationDate < a.CreationDate
       GROUP BY  a.OwnerUserID,
                 a.CreationDate
       ) b ON a.OwnerUserID  = b.OwnerUserID
          AND a.CreationDate = b.CreationDate
```

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43d5f/6)